# Как избавиться от исключения "IOException: File '... ...pdf' cannot be written to"

Tags: android-studio, файлы, исключения

Я хочу скачать по ссылке пдф-файл и открыть его во пдф-ридере. Для этого я указал:

- в манифесте:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  ```
- в классе AppAsyncTasks.java:

  ```
  public static class FileLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {

      private static final String LOG_TAG = "FileLoadingTask";

      .........................

      public FileLoadingTask(final Context cxt,
                             final JSONOrder order,
                             final FileLoadingListener listener) {
      ..................
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          createPdLoading(pdLoading);
          this.url = mOrder.getPreviewlink();
          this.extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
          this.folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "Download");
          this.folder.mkdir();
          this.fileName = mOrder.getOrdercode() + ".pdf";
          this.file = new File(this.folder, this.fileName);
          fileLoadingListener.onBegin();
      }

      @Override
      protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {
          try {
              FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), file);
          } catch (IOException e) {

      //Здесь получаю исключение: IOException: File 'storage/emulated/0/Download/...pdf' cannot be written to
              throwable = e;
          }
          return file;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
          super.onPostExecute(file);
          pdLoading.dismiss();
          fileLoadingListener.onEnd(file);
          if (throwable != null) {
              fileLoadingListener.onFailure(throwable);
          } else {
              fileLoadingListener.onSuccess();
          }
      }

      public interface FileLoadingListener {

          void onBegin();

          void onSuccess();

          void onFailure(Throwable cause);

          void onEnd(File file);

      }
  }
  ```

Однако запись файла на внутренний носитель не происходит - выбрасывается исключение:

> IOException: File 'storage/emulated/0/Download/...pdf' cannot be written to

Как избавиться от этого исключения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено. Необходимо было включить в код инструкции по проверке разрешения на запись во внешнюю память (write to external memory). Для этого в метод onPreExecute() добавим проверку версии и вызов метода checkPermissions():

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            while (checkPermissions()) {
            }
        }
        ... ... ... ...
    }
```

Сам этот метод возвращает значение "истина", если разрешение на запись файлов во внешнюю память отсутствует, и - "ложь", если оно имеется.

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        switch (App.getCurFragContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            case PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                fileLoadingListener.requestPermissions();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

В интерфейс FileLoadingListener добавлен метод requestPermissions(), который вызывается из метода checkPermissions() и имеет следующую реализацию:

```
    @Override
    public void requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                (Activity) mActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                App.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE);
    }
```

Всё.